# Unable to add key value in JSON object using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am stuck in a very weird issue. I have done this so many times previously but this time it's just not working and I am stuck.

```
var updateObj = {};
db.child("symbols/" +name).once('value').then(function(data){
            if(data.exists())
                ticker.val().forEach(function(path){
                        addInJSON(path, data.val());
                });
            })
    //Trying to add some dummy values to test 
    addInJSON("dummy", {val: "pummy"});
    updateObj["dummykey"] = "dummy value";
    for(key in updateObj){
        console.log(key + "  " + updateObj[key]);
    }



function addInJSON(key, value){
    updateObj[key] = value;
}
```

Output looks like this:
Output looks like this:

**Object {dummy: Object, dummykey: "dummy value"}**

```
dummy:Object {val: "pummy"}
dummykey:"dummy value"
watchlist/41HJ5vonrUMMkH7TDwiSdAedhEL2/ADANIPOWER:Object {day_change: 2.25, day_change_percentage: 6.17, day_high: 40.05, …}
watchlist/41HJ5vonrUMMkH7TDwiSdAedhEL2/ARVIND:Object {day_change: -2.75, day_change_percentage: -0.6, day_high: 462.15, …}
watchlist/41HJ5vonrUMMkH7TDwiSdAedhEL2/ASHOKLEY:Object {day_change: 0.05, day_change_percentage: 0.04, day_high: 118.85, …}
```

**PROBLEM**

```
output: Object {dummy: Object, dummykey: "dummy value"}
Expected output: Object {dummy: Object, dummykey: "dummy value", "watchlist/41HJ5vonrUMMkH7TDwiSdAedhEL2/ADANIPOWER" :Object, ...}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `add` values to `objects` you would do this `myObject['someKey'] = 'someValue'`. But if you wanted to add values differently I added an example for that as well. Try the `snippet` to see.

```js
// Example 1
var myObject = {};

myObject['first'] = {};
myObject['second'] = {};

myObject['first']['firstFirst'] = 5;
myObject['first']['firstSecond'] = 6;
myObject['second']['secondFirst'] = 1;
myObject['second']['secondSecond'] = 9;

console.log("This is example 1.");
console.log(myObject);

// Example 2
var myObject2 = {};
Object.assign(myObject2, { first: { firstFirst: 5, firstSecond: 6 } });
Object.assign(myObject2, {second: { secondFirst: 1} });
Object.assign(myObject2['second'], { secondSecond: 9 });

console.log("\nThis is example 2");
console.log(myObject2);
```